# How to follow the lyric to strum in guitar

Tags: chords, improvisation, melody, strumming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I play (and sing) a chord pattern song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/how-do-i-play-and-sing-a-chord-pattern-song)

I am wondering how do I follow the lyric and strumming at the same time when I looking at the chords on the top of the lyrics without and sign of how much duration would be of the chords.

Please Help...

Should I find out the melody of the lyrics first.

Answer (score 3):

If all you have is the words and the chord symbol, then yes, you need to find out the melody first. There's no way to guess from just those pieces; although you could invent your own.

Answer (score 0):

The Melody may not be important here, but you will certainly need to know where the chord changes occur, and usually the technique to understand the strum pattern is to listen to the track or to read the score or sheet music.

This is because the strum pattern often has no connection with the lyrics sung or their rhythm.